# Application Insights disable GET requests every 5 min

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

We have a problem with Application Insights. 
There are a [lot of requests](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U0veX.png) every 5 min to our App Service. All alerts are disabled. Does anyone know what this is and how to disable the logging for that requests?

P.S. He think that this is ResourceHealth monitor, but how to disable it then?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You probably use the "Always On" feature within your application settings. Azure is invoking the root of your site every 5 minutes to keep your app warm. I doubt there is a way to disabling these loggings.

Comment: But you *can* filter them out by just Selecting Filters->Real or synthetic traffic->Real user traffic.

Comment: @juunas Nice hint - didn't know that!

Comment: And what about Continuous WebJobs on my App Service, they need to be Always turned on. Will they work as expected?

Comment: @juunas I need not just filter. but exclude from logging, because it spends free space in Application Insights

Comment: Continuous WebJobs will shut down if the instance goes idle for 20 minutes. Always On prevents that.

Answer (score 2):

With application insights telemetryprocessor you can filter the heartbeat requests (or any other kind of requests) by manually capturing the telemetry.
Have a look at [this](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/request-filtering-in-application-insights-with-telemetry-processor/)